# textile - how do I add a class to a definition list?

Tags: html, css, textile, redcloth

I'm using [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org) to convert some [textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) text into html.

One particular scenario seems particularly apt for using [definition lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3).

With RedCloth, definition lists have this syntax ([source](http://redcloth.org/textile/page-layout/#definition-lists)):

```
- coffee := Hot and black
- tea := Also hot, but a little less black
- milk :=
Nourishing beverage for baby cows.

Cold drink that goes great with cookies. =:
```

I want to add the class "beverages" to that list (so that the generated code looks like `<dl class="beverages">...`). I've tried this:

```
(beverages)- coffee := Hot and black
...
```

I also tried:

```
-(beverage) coffee := Hot and black
-(beverage) tea := Also hot, but a little less black
...
```

This is the way you style the other lists (`ul`s and `ol`s) in textile, but it didn't work for `dl`s. The text was rendered as a literal paragraph (`<p>-(beverage) coffee := Hot and black</p>`)

Is there a syntax for adding classes to definition lists in textile, or must I use raw html instead?

Comment: I assume you mean `class="foo"`? This is an HTML class. There is no such thing as a CSS class (although people mistakenly use the term to mean HTML class, CSS class selector, CSS selector and CSS rule-set — which makes it a really confusing term).

Comment: Your assumption is correct (as per the example). I've removed "css" from the title & body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old - :- syntax does not allow adding classes/ids, but the following will work:

```
;(defclass#defid) Lorem
: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

will produce

```
<dl class="defclass" id="defid">
    <dt>Lorem</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to assign classes or ids to definition lists on textile.

I've created an issue for this here:

http://jgarber.lighthouseapp.com/projects/13054/tickets/208-classes-or-ids-cant-be-specified-in-definition-lists